# Nested for loop Java confusion

Tags: java

Hi i have a beginner question about nested for-loop in java.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = i; j>= 0; j--){
        sum += j;
    }
}
```

so here is my trace table

```
i j sum
1 1 1
  0 1
2 2 2
  1 3
  0 3
```

My question is why is the output at the end of the loop is 4? is it because 3+1?

Comment: You provided your output, which ends with a 3. Then you ask why it ends with a 4. Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: `1 + 2 + 1 = 4`

Comment: That's my trace table, my question is what would be the value of sum at the end of the loop? isn't it supposed to be 3? but when i ran in eclipse it gave me 4.

Comment: In your table, you sum 1 (sum from the first iteration) with 2 (j on the third row), and mark the result as 2. 1 + 2 is 3. Not 2. Why don't you print the value of i, j and sum at eash iteration?

Answer (score 2):

Your trace table is wrong. This is the correct one:

```
i j sum
1 1 1
  0 1
2 2 3
  1 4
  0 4
```

You sum all values of `j` (second column), which essentially is `1 + 0 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 4`.

Comment: So the sum is connected to the next outer loop?

Comment: Not directly. But your variable `j`is connected to the outer loop. And you sum over the values of `j`.

Comment: Is it the same concept if you have


           for(int i = 1; i<=3; i++){
           for(int j = 1; j<=2; j++{
            System.out.print("six");
            }}

it actually printed 6 so its the same concept?

Answer (score 2):

Actually we need to make a correction for your table result:

```
i j sum
1 1 1
  0 1
2 2 2 (sum is 2+1(existing sum, sum is not 0 anymore) )
  1 3 (sum is 3 + 1 = 4)
  0 3 (sum is 4+ 0 = 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The output is 4 because `sum` is:

```
0 + 
1 +
2 + 1 = 
= 4
```

First you add `1`, then `2` and `1`. Your loops sums all triangle numbers below 3. Triangle numbers are sums of numbers from `1` to `n`. These are `1`, `3`, `6`, `10` etc..

Comment: So these numbers are from the trace table in J?

Comment: You made a mistake in your trace. You should use debugger.